# Ionic 3 unable to load external website on ionic app.If so it works in android,but it shows blank screen in IOS

Tags: ionic3

How to load external website when app opens up in ionic 3.I tried all possible solution i.e with plugins and without plugins.It works on android,but it displays blank screen on Ios device. Even though i use Iframe also,but it shows x-frame options: could not loaded website error.How to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the allow-navigation tag. So to solve it I only had to put the  tag into the project's config.xml file.

I came to the solution through the output box in xcode while the simulator was running. There was a message containing the url of the iframe in question and something about "internal navigation rejected".

After, use `cordova platform rm ios, cordova platform add ios` to make this change work. A `cordova clean, cordova build` might work too.